# protractor create a table page object to process tables with different selectors?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, end-to-end, pageobjects

my first post.  I am writing e2e tests in protractor using page objects with javascript/nodejs.  Have read many SO posts on this, read Julie's pages as well as studying [ProtractorPageObjects](https://github.com/Droogans/ProtractorPageObjects).

All of the tables in the application have the same structure.  The only difference is in an attribute: data-row-type can be one of 10 possible values like 'job', 'node', 'rack', etc...

Obviously I can pass in the string to a method and switch in the method to construct the correct selector.  Based on comments in ProTractorPageObjects
I am trying NOT to write the code that way.  Am I being silly here, just use the string and get on with it or is there a way to create such a method without having to pass in the string?

In chapter 5 of the ProTractorPageObjects, in the columns.js file it is mentioned not to use a pattern where a string is passed in to determine what is looked for.

For example:

```
<div id="ee54a74e-17b8-4380-bbd8-2a5087bad7c9" class="tableRow escale-table-row-selected" data-row-type="ipAddress" data-qa-row-number="1">
            <div class="tableCell">
                <span class=""></span>                    ips-172-20-143-20-21
            </div>
            <div class="tableCell">
                <span class=""></span>                    UP
            </div>
            <div class="tableCell">
                <span class=""></span>                    Yes
            </div>
```

...

Another Table:

```
<div id="6f529383-c0f3-49b7-9ccb-c8db2b0c75a9" class="tableRow escale-table-row-selected" data-row-type="fileSystem" data-qa-row-number="0">
            <div class="tableCell">
                <span class=""></span>                    card-view<div><span class="fa fa-square success fileSystemIndicator"></span><span id="6f529383-c0f3-49b7-9ccb-c8db2b0c75a9-share" class="fa fa-square fileSystemIndicator success"></span><span id="6f529383-c0f3-49b7-9ccb-c8db2b0c75a9-accessRule" class="fa fa-square fileSystemIndicator success"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tableCell">
                <span class=""></span>                    UP
            </div>
            <div class="tableCell">
                <span class=""></span>                    Yes
            </div>
 ......
```

Comment: Can you post some example of what you want to accomplish? I have no idea what you are talking about :) Also where is columns.js and  chapter 5 of the ProTractorPageObjects...

Comment: @cvakiitho I think it's the question formatting that made the question unclear - there were HTML code blocks not properly shown - fixed that.

Comment: @alecxe that, and not having a morning coffee before opening SO... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly okay to construct your selector based on a string value that is passed into a method and then used to match a `div` element's `data-row-type` attribute. `data-row-type` attribute in your case is quite a "data-oriented" attribute (well, compare it to, for instance, `style` attribute - this one is very much UI/style oriented and is always a poor choice to rely your locators on) and uniquely distinguishes/defines the page blocks on a page.

Example implementation:

```
function getTable (tableType) {
    return element(by.css("div[data-row-type='" + tableType + "']"));
}
```

Sample usage:

```
getTable("ipAddress");
getTable("fileSystem");
```

Comment: how did you fix the formatting?  It looked weird to me when I posted, but being a newbie I thought it might be 'normal'.  Should have checked the real posting.  Thanks for doing that.

Comment: Shoot, hit cr by mistake.  Here is what I am trying to do.  For almost all of the gui I need to get what is displayed, and then compare it to what the cli returns.  So mostly I am displaying a page that usually has two tables on it.  A jobs table for that resource .... e.g. filesystem. and the table that displays the file systems already created.  So I want to get all of the table text entries and the table/column headers and some colored boxes.  I then compare each 'row' to what the cli returns.  Promises seem to make tasks like this a lot harder than they should be.  Comment helps @alecxe